# recoding a few values within a few columns and leave everything else within those column intact

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, dplyr, tidyverse

In my data.frame `d2`, I'm trying to `recode` a few values within a few columns and leave everything else within those column intact. Specifically, I want to do the following:

`profic`: replace 77s with 99s;
`cf.type`: replace 15s with 99s;
`Length`: replace 0s with 1s and replace 3s with 2s;
`graded`: replace 88s with 99s.

I have tried the following but it seems I don't get the desired result (i.e., *the other values in the recoded columns get deleted*), is there a fix to this?

```
library(tidyverse)

d2 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m/master/v13.csv')

d3 <- mutate(d2, profic = recode(profic, "77"="99"),
       cf.type = recode(cf.type, "15"="99"),
       Length = recode(Length, "0"="1", "3"="2"),
       graded = recode(graded, "88"="99")
       )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace numeric values use :

```
library(dplyr)

d3 <- mutate(d2, profic = recode(profic, `77` = 99L),
                 cf.type = recode(cf.type, `15` = 99L),
                 Length = recode(Length, `0` =1L, `3`= 2L),
                 graded = recode(graded, `88`= 99L))
```

Answer (score 0):

recode is quite particular about variable types. The message I get when I run your code is `Warning message: Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply .default` .
If you run `glimpse(d2)` you will see that `profic`, `cf.type`, `Length` and `graded` are all `int` (integers). You can specify that a number is an integer in R by adding an L to the end like so `9L`. Compare `str(9)` and `str(9L)`, the first is numeric and the second is an integer.

You also need to remove the quotes on the RHS only - if you leave the replacement values quoted they will be interpreted as string literals instead of numbers. If you remove the quotes on the LHS you will get a different error, which is beyond the scope of this answer.

```
d2 <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/m/master/v13.csv')

d3 <- mutate(d2, profic = recode(profic, "77"=99L),
             cf.type = recode(cf.type, "15"=99L),
             Length = recode(Length, "0"=1L, "3"=2L),
             graded = recode(graded, "88"=99L)
)
```